# WPF listviewItem styling trigger not working

Tags: wpf, styling, listviewitem

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding TeamTagsLiveDTO}" x:Name="teamTagsGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="SortByPlayerTags" Style="{StaticResource TeamTagsListViewStyle}">
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource teamtagsstyleLive}" Text="{Binding TeamTagsName1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

i have this piece code as shown above:

The setter elements are working fine but the triggers are not working. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Please add more sample code than just the close tag you have shown here.

Comment: thanks!  Can you describe in more detail what is happening now and what isn't working?  For instance, is the mouseover effect triggering upon the mouseover event but then not going away when the mouse moves out of the element?

Comment: The triggers are not firing. when an item is selected , the background should change to black. But its not happening. Similar is the case for IsMouseover trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Turns out Control Template handles the background property and the highlght color of the ListViewItem and not the ListViewItem itself.

Comment: Can you detail how you fixed it?